# How to change the cell using reloadData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Good day. How to change the count and label of the cells by clicking using reloadData?

[image]

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{        
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];        
    NSLog(@"test");                 
    [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:3];       
    [tableView reloadData];         
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by change the number and names of the cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the number of rows in section you should modify your dataSource from your delegate method. You shouldn't call any of dataSource methods.

Below you can find one of the simplest way to modify data of yoru table view:

```
// In your category or header file:    
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger numberOfRows;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.numberOfRows = 1;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) {
    self.numberOfRows = 3;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

//Method in your table view datasrouce
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.numberOfRows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code reacting to the selection of a cell, update the datasource of your `UiTableView`
and after that reload the table.